# How to express an unary operator in infix notation (derived from a binary expression tree)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, trees

I'm a little confused on the formalism for infix notation and its relationship to inorder traversal of the binary tree representing an expression. When an unary operator (like a $-$ sign or a $\neg$ operator) appears in the binary tree, it appears as the parent of the variable or expression that it is applied to. (The variable or expression that the unary operator acts on is necessarily the only child of the unary operator vertex.) I know that infix notation is produced by an inorder traversal of the binary tree, which would visit the unary operator's child before visiting the unary operator. I would think that this would mean that unary operators would follow their operands in infix notation, but every example that I can find has an unary operator precede its operand, as it would in the standard expression. Which is the correct way to form the expression? Am I misunderstanding infix notation and/or inorder traversal?

Edit: I'm including my textbook's (recursive) definition of an inorder traversal of an arbitrary ordered rooted tree, which extends beyond traversal of a full binary tree:

> Let $T$ be an ordered rooted tree with root $r$. If $T$ consists only of $r$, then $r$ is the inorder traversal of $T$. Otherwise, suppose that $T_1$, $T_2$, . . . , $T_n$ are the subtrees at $r$ from left to right. The inorder traversal begins by traversing $T_1$ in inorder, then visiting $r$. It continues by traversing $T_2$ in inorder, then $T_3$ in inorder, . . . , and finally $T_n$ in inorder.

So for example, consider an ordered rooted tree consisting of a root $r$ with three children (leaves) $T_1$, $T_2$, and $T_3$. The inorder traversal of the tree would be $T_1$, $r$, $T_2$, $T_3$. If any of the $T_i$ were not leaves, the inorder traversals of these subtrees would take the place of their root in the previous expression.

Comment: It’s not really my field, and I don’t know what is conventionally done, but one gets the right result if one defines inorder traversal so that if a node has only one child, the node is visited before the child. Equivalently, if a node has only one child, think of it as the right child.

Comment: Well, if you add unary operators to you tree, it is no longer a binary tree (the unary operators don’t have the necessary two children). Hence you can not simply do an inorder traversal of that tree because “inorder” does not specify how to handle non-binary internal nodes. For “real” mathematical expressions you basically have to specify how to handle each type of operator node, some as inorder (if they have to children), some as pre- or postorder, some in even more exotic ways (e.g. binomial coefficients).

Comment: My textbook gives a definition of inorder traversal that extends to all ordered rooted tree, which I've appended to my original question. An inorder traversal of a vertex with a single child would involve traversing the child inorder, then visiting the vertex. However, if the vertex corresponds to an unary operator in a mathematical expression, then shouldn't the unary operator come after its operand in the infix representation, since the operator vertex is visited after its child in the inorder traversal of the tree?